# Why am I 100.3% complete with the campaign?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've played all the way through the campaign on Veteran, and I went back and got all the campaign achievements and located all the intel.  However, on the main menu screen, the game tells me I'm 100.3% complete with the campaign.

Having a percentage higher than 100% is normal in things like the Multiplayer component, where it gives you a percentage based on how far along you are in the prestige track (so you have 100% at level 80, and then 200% at level 80 first prestige, 300% at level 80 second prestige, etc) but I don't understand why I have exactly this percentage for the single player.

Comment: No one likes an overachiever... I would assume, but have no way of confirming, that whatever they add up in the background just has a bit of a rounding error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wondered this same thing for the longest time but I figured out the answer. You have 100.3% because on the level "Mind the Gap" there are 3 pieces of intel even though it only says there is 2. So since you found the 3rd one it counts it as .3% since it is not registered in the game. If you don't grab that one though you won't get the collect all 46 pieces of intel and you will only have 100%. It is just stupid that they put that 1 extra one in there without telling you it was on the level.

Comment: They are coming out with additional campaign content so it wont matter in a few weeks, there will be 150% of the campaign to complete.

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't thought about the Mind the Gap weirdness.  When you wake up after the "subway crash" scene, I believe that it will say "X/1 enemy intel found" whereas earlier in the level it will tell you "X/2 enemy intel found" so perhaps they just did a bad job of QA'ing that part of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Call of Duty wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Glitches), it's just a glitch plain and simple. I found it unusual too, so looked into it a bit and that's all it was, just a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the extra .3 after getting the secret achievement "Flight Attendant".  It may be a coincidence, but perhaps they didn't want someone who missed the secret achievement to have less than 100% if they'd done everything else.

Comment: In the future, you should back up your answers.

Answer (score -1):

It is a mistake on part of the developers.

Nicks's answer about "Mind the Gap" is wrong because it actually has two parts, the first says 0/2 and the second 0/1 (or vice versa), so it's never 3 out of 2.